# jQuery: How to open file open dialog box on click button

Tags: jquery, fileopendialog

How can I make a dialog box open on click of button on `swallow` rendering.
It can be dynamically repeatable button as it is inside `li`.

[image]

//Code

```
var wrapper = $(this).parents(".file-upload-wrapper")[0];
$(wrapper).find('.attachment-button-div')[0].click(function() {
 $(wrapper).find('.attachment-button')[0].trigger('click');

});

$(wrapper).find('.file-upload').change(function() {
 $('input[type=text]').val($(this).val());
});
```

But it is not working as expected . Any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this. create buttons and corresponding invisible file input to each button. Add some jQuery to trigger/click  corresponding  invisible file input:

```js
function openfile(a) {
  $(a).trigger('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" onclick='openfile("#file-input3")' class="file-button"> Open</button>
<input id="file-input1" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />

<button id="button2" onclick='openfile("#file-input2")' class="file-button"> Open</button>
<input id="file-input2" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />

<button id="button3" onclick='openfile("#file-input3")' class="file-button"> Open</button>
<input id="file-input3" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but this should be checked with Parent child. else it won't work in my case.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar I didn't get that. please explain your requirement.

Comment: My requirement is to open a dialog box on click attachment button. This button can be repeatable . So we have to check which button is clicked and the file should be checked accordingly.

Comment: As above solution won't work for me because my button can be repeated . And this solution will work for only for one button.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar now anwser updated. now you add open multiple file input

Answer (score 0):

why you don't simply use input tag with file type? It opens the choose file dialog box.

```html
<h3>Please choose your attachment:</h3>
<form action="">
  <label for="myfile">Select files:</label>
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" multiple><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as it needs to be swallow rendering I can't use input tag.